# eliminating empty lines in text files with python

Tags: python, lines

i have two columns of numbers in a text file which is the columns of time and  stress respectively which i get it from an analysis in abaqus finite element package ! i want to get ride of the first row which have the string objects and the second row which is empty line . ( also the four line from the bottom of my text file is empty lines ! )
my problem is how to eliminate this two lines and then creating two list of numbers for each columns !

my text file is as follows :

```
              X               FORCE-1     

            0.                 0.         
           10.E-03            98.3479E+03 
           12.5E-03          122.947E+03  
           15.E-03           147.416E+03  
           18.75E-03         183.805E+03  
           22.5E-03          215.356E+03  
           26.25E-03         217.503E+03  
           30.E-03           218.764E+03  
           33.75E-03         219.724E+03  
           37.5E-03          220.503E+03  
           43.125E-03        221.938E+03  
           51.5625E-03       228.526E+03  
           61.5625E-03       233.812E+03
```

code for extracting the data of time and stresses and creating seperate lists for each is as follows :

```
time = []
stress = []
count = 0
with open('txtFORCE-1.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip() #removing extra spaces from right and left 
        temp = line.split(" ") # spliting the result of the last line
        if count>=3 :
           time.append(temp[0].strip())  #removing extra spaces and append
           stress.append(temp[0].strip()) #removing extra spaces and append
        count=count+1

print(time)
print(stress)
```

i don't use this code and i get this from my friend and i don't really sure for the accuracy of that !

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code that you've tried so far? Also elaborate on:  *how to eliminate this two lines and then creating two list of numbers*.

Comment: You show some code you could try, so what exactly is your question? Also, do you want the output to be two lists of numbers, or a new text file with those lines removed?

Comment: i write the code , but i don't really trust on this code because i don't use it so far ! i firstly should eliminate the two lines and then use that ! what i'm seeking is to create two lists of numbers for each number columns ! one list only contains the time columns and one the stresses !

Comment: I still don't see a question in your last comment. What exactly are *you* asking *us*? Are you asking if that sample code is valid?

Comment: @Rory when i use this code , i get something like this : ['0.', '10.E-03', '12.5E-03', '15.E-03', '18.75E-03', '22.5E-03', '26.25E-03', '30.E-03', '33.75E-03', '37.5E-03', '43.125E-03', '51.5625E-03', '61.5625E-03', '71.5625E-03', '821.563E-03', '831.563E-03', '841.563E-0, '1.', '', '', '', ''] which have four empty elemnts after the last element ('1')

Comment: for eliminating this empty elements i'm considering to eliminate  firstly the empty lines of my text file !

Comment: do i elaborate my question to you @Rory ? (i want only two list which have only numbers but not empty elements , how can i get ride of that empty ones ? )

Comment: A possibility: `line.strip()` when evaluated as Boolean will return True when it is a non-empty string and False when empty. You could use this to skip over the blank lines within your existing `for` structure (look into `continue`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is revised code that should answer your question about removing empty items from the final lists.

```
time = []
stress = []
with open('txtFORCE-1.txt') as file:
    for count, line in enumerate(file):
        temp = line.split()  # remove extra spaces and split
        if count >= 2 and len(temp) > 1:
           time.append(temp[0])
           stress.append(temp[1])

print(time)
print(stress)
```

The change that removed the empty items is `if count >= 2 and len(temp) > 1:` which does nothing if the line did not contain at least two items. I also skipped over just the first two lines (your code skipped three), improved the splitting of the line, and made some other lines more pythonic. Note that both lists contain strings, not numbers. That could be changed if you instead use `time.append(float(temp[0]))` etc., but this will fail if any of the items is not actually a number in a correct format.